# How do I change the desktop Conky appears on with dual desktops?

Tags: 10.10, multiple-monitors

I recently purchased a new monitor for my laptop, and I'm using it for dual desktops. I'm using my new monitor as the primary "desktop" instead of my laptop screen. However, Conky is still on my laptop's screen. How can I move Conky onto my main monitor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set or increase the value of gap_x property so that it is larger than the width of your laptop screen. This should push conky onto your second monitor.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this and it worked, so I was just about to answer my own question. gap_x 1450 worked perfectly.